# Where is Visual Studio 2022 storing the nupkg-files

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2022, packagereference

I use Visual Studio 2022. There I have seen, that it stores the NuGet-Packages-Reference in the csproj-File as PackageReference.
Now I am searching for the nupkg-files. Where are they stored in Visual Studio 2022? I didn't find them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several locations where the nuget files are stored and/or decompressed. You get them with the following command:

```
dotnet nuget locals -l all
```

For me, this returns:

```
C:\projects>dotnet nuget locals -l all
http-cache: C:\Users\PMF\AppData\Local\NuGet\v3-cache
global-packages: C:\Users\PMF\.nuget\packages\
temp: C:\Users\PMF\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch
plugins-cache: C:\Users\PMF\AppData\Local\NuGet\plugins-cache
```

Comment: I wonder why Microsoft no longer relies on solution/project level packages folder ?

Comment: @BaltoStar Probably mostly to save bandwidth. Many packages are used by many projects, and if you're working with a lot of solutions, downloading them each time wastes bandwidth and disk space.

Comment: @PFM for me it was c:\users\\[myprofile]\.nuget

Comment: @LarryAultman Yea, that's the default for most situations. It's the "global-packages" folder mentioned above.

Comment: @PMF How you include a `.css ` file in `_Layout.cshtml` with this referencing approach? I have a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76673639/visual-studio-2022-v-17-6-5-link-installed-nuget-package-css-file-in-layout)

Answer (score 3):

This document might be useful to you:
[nuget.config reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file)

> The location of the default global packages folder. The default is
> %userprofile%.nuget\packages (Windows) or ~/.nuget/packages
> (Mac/Linux).

Comment: I wonder why Microsoft no longer relies on solution/project level packages folder ?

Comment: @BaltoStar most likely is the size of the project folders when you are working on multiple projects that do the same thing (ie use the same versions of packages)